# Markings/smudges/wear on steel springform pans

Tags: equipment

[image: pan]

Hi folks.  Can someone tell me what the markings are on this steel springform pan?  I tried cleaning it with Bar Keeper's Friend already.  Also interested to know if they are still okay to use if they cannot be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like normal markings on well used baking tins. It's fat that polymerised from heat (same procedure as for seasoning cast iron, just unintentionally). It's perfectly safe to use the pan like that. It can theoretically be removed with outrageous amounts of elbow grease and heavy duty cleaning chemicals, but it's not worth the effort in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest boiling this in a larger pot with baking soda. This will often lift these right off or require very minimal scrubbing. You can try four tablespoons baking soda to 1/2 cup water* for difficult stains (or as little as 2 tbsp baking soda to one quart for non-stick such as enameled cast iron). If the stains don't come out on their own, let the pan cool, then rinse and scrub with a paste of baking soda and water. You can also try vinegar and baking soda, but you may find simply boiling with a baking soda solution is all you need. Please post your results.

*Depending on the pan and the situation, less baking soda works. I have used this trick with great success in my french oven (aka enameled dutch oven) with much less baking soda.

Comment: Can you confirm that 4 tbsp baking soda to 1/2 cup water is the correct proportion to boil it in?  This seems like it would be very thick.

Comment: Marc — sorry if my answer wasn't clear. You'll have to experiment with how much is needed for your material and staining/burnt-on food. You could start with less and see how it goes and then try again with more and/or scrub with a baking soda paste. You can also leave overnight in non-rust metal after boiling. I have had great success using this method.

Comment: I boiled them in some baking soda, let cool, and scrubbed in a baking soda paste and it seems to have helped a bit with some hidden rust and bits of junk that floated in the water but the black markings are still pretty bad.  Thanks for trying!  I'm going to ignore them.